# Win 10, how to Update a Registry parameter

Tags: windows-registry, windows-10

I need to modify an existing parameter on Win 10 registry, so I executed:

```
reg update [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced] "Hidden"="1"
```

It did not work, so I did `reg /?` and I notice the update parameter is not even there.

I checked the other parameter, and it seems like there is none for update. Any suggestion?

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/607572/how-do-i-modify-the-data-of-an-existing-registry-key-value-name-from-cmd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ADD` command to overwrite an existing value; if you also add the `/f` option, the value will be overwritten without asking for confirmation.

Also, your syntax is wrong: you must use `/v` and `/d` to specify the value and the data, and you must also use `/t` to specify the value type.

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response, it works very well and turns the parameter on the registry to 1, but it does not do what I was thinking it will do.  What I wanted to be done was if the checkbox on explorer had been turned on to display the hidden files/Folders it to be turned off by an script at the time of Logon... but I noticed it does not do anything to do with that... Have any idea how that can be done?  Regards, Jeff P.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response, it works very well and turns the parameter on the registry to 1, Sorry I was in rush and at first I thought it does not work but now I noticed yes it works for both files and folder...  Regards, Jeff P.

Comment: That's a completely different question, and should be asked as such.

Comment: Thanks... I know how that can be done... Thanks you again for your answer.